# How to show Tikz/PGFPlot axis scale as text instead of scientific notation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have plotted a pgfplot bar graph using data from a csv file. The data has numbers in the hundreds of millions and the graph y axis is automatically scaled and shows the scale in scientific notation. Is it possible to change this notation to text? As in show (millions) instead of (10^8)?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,]{data/test.csv}\datatable
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \color{darkgrey}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=.3cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=5cm,
            ymin=0,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabels from table={\datatable}{Month},
            x tick label style={font=\normalsize, rotate=45, anchor=east},
            ylabel={Sales}]
            \addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={NumSales}]{\datatable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Total number of sales per month}
    \label{fig:total_sales}
\end{figure}
```

[image: output plot]

Comment: Please make your code fragment as compilable small document, which also contain table with data presented by diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
scaled y ticks=manual:{millions}{\pgfmathparse{#1/10^6}},
```

This is a *full* compilable example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
Month,NumSales
1,123456789
2,145678923
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,]{test.csv}\datatable
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \color{darkgrey}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            scaled y ticks=manual:{millions}{\pgfmathparse{#1/10^6}},
            bar width=.3cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=5cm,
            ymin=0,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabels from table={\datatable}{Month},
            x tick label style={font=\normalsize, rotate=45, anchor=east},
            ylabel={Sales}]
            \addplot [fill=red] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={NumSales}]{\datatable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Total number of sales per month}
    \label{fig:total_sales}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, in order to give an example I had to make up some date (probably not the one you are using), to define a color (not the one you are using, perhaps it is somewhere but how would I know), and to complete  the code (`\documentclass` etc.). For the future, I'd kindly like to ask you to provide a complete example (see also [Zarko's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532744/how-to-show-tikz-pgfplot-axis-scale-as-text-instead-of-scientific-notation/532750#comment1347103_532744)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This will work for my current data, but would it automatically change to a different unit if new data were only in thousands for example?

Comment: @LEJ no, it wouldn't. One may potentially cook up something that does that, but in order to do so, one would need clear prescriptions.The `units` library achieves something of that sort, maybe you want to have a look at section **5.14 Units in Labels** of the pgfplots manual v1.16.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will take a look at that package for future reference :)